# VB.Net login form can not connect to Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I got this code off the internet and was playing with it to make a login form, but I can't figure why can't it connect to my database, any ideas? I'm pretty sure I got the right string connection.

Also sorry I can see it doesn't like me pasting all my code in the "Share some code so I'm posting it like this:`ignore this` https://pastebin.com/TUUjPhrP

EDIT: This is what I get after when I run it: `ignore this`https://pastebin.com/HAyrYxBe

EDIT2: I also get this [Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\User\source\repos\MaterialStock\MaterialStock\inventoryDataSet.Designer.vb'.

EDIT3: The 1st link was updated with my new code.

Comment: Edit question to show error message and specify line that errors. Step debug. Should be able to post code within question. I have seen questions with a lot more code than that.

Comment: It trows me this bit at the end: Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll

Edit: Also this: [Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\User\source\repos\MaterialStock\MaterialStock\inventoryDataSet.Designer.vb'.

Comment: This info should be in the question, not in comments. Question no longer reflects code with issue since you edited code for correct table name. Edit your question to post code and error info in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the filepath between apostrophes.

`conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\User\Desktop\inventory.accdb'"`

Comment: Ok I made it just Users and the rows username and password are named the same way in my table but it still isn't working so it's probably something else?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: The apostrophes was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Okay, glad it worked. Please mark answer as accepted if it really does resolve issue.